# Arguments for the Seek and Destroy Freecode camp challenge

Tags: javascript, function, filter, arguments, iteration

I'm trying to understand the Seek and Destroy challenge below.

Task: You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.

```
This is the initial code below:
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

After several (really) several attempts and looking at other people's code, I was able to resolve the task. However, I think it was more out of luck. I’ve copied my code below, but I was hoping someone could clarify a couple of things for me.

1. The code below passes whether I return val or args within the iterateThroughArray function. Why is that?
2. If I am supposed to be comparing ALL arguments against the first argument, where in this code am I indicating that? I kept thinking I needed to splice the first argument to compare all other arguments against it or create a variable for argument[0]. Any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated!

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
      var args = Array.from(arguments); //this also converts them to an array
       var iterateThroughArr = function (val) {
         if (args.indexOf(val) ===-1){
            return args;
          }
       };
       return arr.filter(iterateThroughArr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound a lot to take in but here is my explanation

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
      var args = Array.from(arguments); //Here arr is converted to [Array(6),2,3]
      //console.log(args)
    /*   var iterateThroughArr = function (val) {
         if (args.indexOf(val) ===-1){
            return args;
          }
       };
     
     return arr.filter(iterateThroughArr);
     */
     
     // to make more clear the above code can be rewritten as below
     var arr = arr.filter(function (val) {
          console.log("args = "+ args + " val = " + val + " indexOf(val) "  + args.indexOf(val) )
         // here you are itterating through each arr val which in this case is[1,2,3,1,2,3]
         // if you dont believe me uncomment the next console.log() and see the output
        // console.log(val) 
         if (args.indexOf(val) ===-1){
          // here is where the magic happens
          // Now you are checking if val exisists by using a builtin method called .indexOf()
          // In general, .indexOf() returns -1 if a value does not exist within an array
          //Below is working example
          /* var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
            console.log(array.indexOf(1)) // 0 since it is located at index 0
            console.log(array.indexOf(5)) // 4 since it is located at index 4
            console.log(array.indexOf(10))  // -1 since it does not exisit 
             */ 
           // Therefore, if value passes the above if statement 
          //then that means it doesnot exisit on args([Array(6),2,3])
           //which as a result will be included on the filtered array
           
            return args;
          }
       });
       
       return arr;
     
    }
    
    
 var val =    destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
 //console.log(val)
```

Basically, what you need to understand is how filter works and how .indexOf works.
For more detail visit Mozilla documentation: [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Let me know if you have any concern

Comment: thank you so much! this is great! 1 follow-up question: does indexOf only work with arrays, or can it be used with strings as well?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  // arr1 is equal to the array inside arr
  var arr1 = arr.slice(arguments);
  // arr2 becomes an array with the arguments 2 & 3
  var arr2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  // this function compares the two and returns an array with elements not equal to the arguments
  return arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function (item) {
    return !arr1.includes(item) || !arr2.includes(item)
  })
}


destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```